# Flutter full screen notification like WhatsApp call

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter, notifications

I want to create a full screen notification. I have achieved a notification by using the firebase messaging. What changes do I need to make it a full screen notification like WhatsApp call which contain some action buttons and ring sound.
[WhatsApp Calling Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF5w2.jpg)

Comment: could you find any solution for?

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Comment: Till now I don't find any solutions regarding this :(